# c# https call with crt and key file with passphrase

Tags: c#, https, httpclient, x509certificate

I have a crt  and key file along with a passphrase.

I am using these successfully via Postman to call an external API.
How do I do this in c#?

I see examples of using X509Certificate with httpclient but Idont see any options for a constructor whereI can use with 2 files and set the passphrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET won't do this for you easily.

Your best bet, honestly, is to use something like OpenSSL to glue the cert and key together into a PFX.

The answer shall now continue assuming you decided not to do that.

There's no dearth of questions asking how to load a key without the certificate, e.g.:

- [Digital signature in c# without using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48905438/6535399)
- [How to parse(Convert to RSAParameters) X.509 private key in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44106066/6535399)
- [Create RSACryptoServiceProvider object using RSA private key file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38841563/6535399)
- [How is a private key encrypted in a pem certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43674870/6535399)

Once you've figured out how to load the key you have a key and a certificate, and they don't understand each other.  There are solutions.

### The safest and easiest next step:

If you are on .NET Core, or are using .NET Framework 4.7.2, you can use

```
X509Certificate2 certWithKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(privateKey);
```

If you're adding certWithKey to an X509Store you either need to have used a persisted key, or export to PFX and import it back with `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet`

### In distant second:

If (all of):

- You're on .NET Framework (not .NET Core)
- Your key is an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` or a `DSACryptoServiceProvider`
- Your key was loaded into a key container (`!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName)`)
- You either haven't gotten this certificate from an X509Store, or you aren't afraid of potentially unexpected side effects

then you could use the setter of X509Certificate2.PrivateKey.

### Final thoughts

There are some P/Invoke recommendations in the bottom of my answer to [.NET Standard - Merge a certificate and a private key into a .pfx file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44465574/6535399) for making a PFX.  Once you've made a PFX you are back in "simple" territory.

Comment: thanks @bartonjs for reply. So if I change to pfx(to make life easier) can I use X509Certificate(
 string fileName,
 SecureString password) ctr

Comment: @Noel yep. Though you should only bother with SecureString if you are prompting a user via `Console.ReadKey()`, the string overloads are better for most people’s needs